# Document has ambiguous configuration: sales_flat_quote_address

Tags: magento2

Following error occurred while performing **data migration** from 1.9.2.4 to 2.3.1. Please, assist.

> Document has ambiguous configuration: sales_flat_quote_address

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because you've marked a document (database table or view) to be ignored, but then tried to specify further rules on the same document later on in your map file.

For example, you might have tried to do this:

```
        <ignore>
             <document>cms_page</document>
        </ignore>
```

Then later on, had a rule like this:

```
        <move>
            <field>cms_page.root_template</field>
            <to>cms_page.page_layout</to>
        </move>
```

It's ambiguous because you're trying to perform an operation on a document which has been ignored.